# Go sftp download file| 3pp server return `file is not extractable`

Tags: go, sftp

```
if f, err = s.client.Open(path.Join(remotePath, fileName)); err != nil {
return err
}

if err = os.MkdirAll(localPath, os.ModePerm); err != nil {
    return err
}
if localFile, err = os.Create(path.Join(localPath, fileName)); err != nil {
    return err
}
if n, err := f.WriteTo(localFile); err != nil {
return err
}
```

Comment: You can find an example here: https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoSFTPtoS3/blob/3c8020c49aeb6f8f6ea8f75dffbac9b238ab7a9f/main.go#L164

Comment: It seems that the example is not useful;
I follow this master's advice and resolve this issue.
https://github.com/pkg/sftp/issues/510